# Equivalence test for nonparametric one-way ANOVA

Tags: nonparametric, equivalence

I have hypothesised equivalence among 3 repeated measures. The data are such that a nonparametric approach would be needed.

What I have considered, but not necessarily know how to implement correctly:

1. Compare confidence intervals at `100 * (1-2 * alpha)%` for a Friedman ANOVA. This may be represented in a graph.
2. Attempt something like a two one-sided t-test procedure, but for a Friedman ANOVA.

Could someone point me to a resource where I could figure out how to do this?

Comment: Suggestions on how to improve my question would also be appreciated.